# Write a script to change to directory dynamically

Tags: python, ruby, bash, zsh

I wanna finish the task by Ruby or Python.

Suppose I have some folders under a specific folder.

And wanna go to the folder by typing shortcut in terminal rather than typing the abspath of folder.

Eg. if I type `cd_python` ,it should match the prefix `cd_`

and the suffix `python` will lead me to the python folder.

If I type `cd_ruby` it should lead me to  `~/Dropbox/notes/ruby`

I have  dozens of sort of folders

Please give me some hints, thanks

```
~/Dropbox/notes/python
~/Dropbox/notes/ruby
~/Dropbox/notes/rails
...
```

Comment: How is `cd_python` better than `cd python`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to finish this task in python or ruby. The easiest is in bash:

```
#~/.bash_profile

function change {
    cd ~/Dropbox/notes
    cd $1
}
```

Place this script in your .bash_profile and it will get loaded when terminal starts.

Then just type `change dirname` and you will go to `/Dropbox/notes/dirname`

This way you can use whatever dirname you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CDPATH variable instead:

```
CDPATH=~/Dropbox/notes:.
```

Then, `cd python` will take you to ~/Dropbox/notes/python. Tab-completion might work too.